# Topology generated by $(X,d_1)$ is contained in Topology genereted by $(X,d_2)$. What can be deduced from this?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$ where $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ generated by metric $d_1$ and $d_2$ respectively. Then what can be said about the metric spaces.

My Observations are as follows:

1. As $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$ $\implies$ Every open ball in $(X,d_1)$ contains an
   open ball from $(X,d_2) \implies (x_n)$ convergent in $(X,d_2)$ is also convergent in $(X,d_1)$ $\implies$ $id: 
      (X,d_2)\rightarrow (X,d_1)$ is continuous.

My Questions are:

1. I think  $id^{-1}:(X,d_1)\rightarrow(X,d_2)$ is not continuous. (i.e there are
   sequences in $(X,d_1)$ which is not convergent in $(X,d_2)$.)But I cannot
   think of any counterexample.
2. A few nice examples of metric spaces with the above property.
3. What other information can be drawn from this given assumption?

Comment: Is $τ_2$ strictly containing $τ_1$? Notice that $id: (X,d_1) \to (X,d_2)$ is continuous iff the two topologies are equal.

Comment: You mean assuming $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$ we have $id:(X,d_1)→(X,d_2)$  is continuous iff the two topologies are equal. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Indeed, a sequence/net converging in $\tau_2$ converges in $\tau_1$ as well. That's a straight forward application of the definition of convergence.
2. Neither the identity nor its inverse has to be continuous. Consider any topological (metric) space $(X,\tau)$ and let $\tau'$ be the discrete topology (which is metrical as well). Then $id:(X,\tau')\to (X,\tau)$ is continuous but its inverse $id^{-1}$ is continuous if and only if $\tau$ is discrete. This should give you plenty examples, e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean and discrete metrics.

Not much can be said beyond that. Some axioms of separation are preserved under $\tau_1\subseteq \tau_2$ condition, but you are dealing with metric spaces to begin with.

Comment: Is there any other nontrivial example? i.e examples not involving discrete metric?

Comment: @Saikat sure, take again any non-discrete $X$ with its discrete version $X'$, take any non-discrete $Y$ and consider $X\times Y$ and $X'\times Y$.

Comment: @Saikat other examples include the Euclidean metric and the post office metric (or the river metric as well) on the plane.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Isn't the Euclidean metric equivalent to the post office metric?

Comment: @freakish No, only around the origin (if the origin is the post office point), other points are isolated.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma oh, right, for some reason I was thinking about taxicab. Thanks!

Comment: @freakish it was one of the first examples in my metric spaces course, first year at uni.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am not aware of the post office metric and river metric. Could you please give me the definition?

Comment: @Saikat have you searched online yet?

Comment: I found them. Thankyou.